# Shortcut Icon in Visual Sourcesafe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I am using Visual Sourcesafe 8.0. While working on it, accedentally the icon of the files in the project changed to a shortcut type icon. That is one with a black arrow. I couldn't find an option to restore the files to original form. That is icons without arraow.

Any one knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution for this issue from below thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3798c5c7-2795-426b-bc60-de6c6a8f5b98/unsharing-files?forum=vssourcecontrol